# Find specific parent folder and delete files inside sub-folders in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

What I want to happen is delete non-images in `assets/uploads` folder but skip the `uploads` folder if the parent folder is not `assets` folder.

```
site1.dev/assets/uploads (delete non-images)
site2.dev/assets/uploads (delete non-images)
site3.dev/assets/uploads (delete non-images)
site4.dev/uploads (skip deletion)
site5.dev/assets/uploads (delete non-images)
```

This is the code that I used `find assets/uploads -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f` but it tedious to run this code each site.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To delete "none-images" as described, you need to first discover the image extensions that are being used and ignore them with find through the -not flag

```
find ./assets/uploads -type f -not /assets/uploads/*.img -not /assets/uploads/*.jpeg -delete
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer to my own quesion `find . -path '*/assets/uploads/*.php' -type f -delete`